# Angular dynamaic view attach and detach inside a ngFor

Tags: angular

I am facing a problem where i have a chat-list items which is loaded  dynamically. on click of every list item i have to open/close a static component/section let say recations menu, right below that perticular chat item(see in this image).

[image]

what i have done is i am able to add new componenet below selected chat item, but not able to remove that component.

```
let factory = this.CFR.resolveComponentFactory(ReactionComponent);
let newNode = document.createElement('div');
newNode.id = 'placeholder';
document.getElementById(id)?.appendChild(newNode);

const ref = factory.create(this.injector, [], newNode);
this.app.attachView(ref.hostView);
```

this is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zphhqv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchat-component%2Fchat.component.ts) example(please ignore bad css and design).
ps: i also tried with view-containers but also not able to get view-containers id in dynamic ngfor list.

also i am open for any new way of doing it, as chat list can be big so don't want to do it with div show /hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way is to hold the `ComponentRefs` in a list, set it to the `ReactionComponent` and back via `EventEmitter`.
You can the list (you see below) handle with *search and work with indexes, too*, but search the ref is the more flexible way, I think.

#### chat.component.ts

```
private dynamicComponents: ComponentRef<any>[] = [];
// ....
 openReaction(id: any) {
    let factory = this.CFR.resolveComponentFactory(ReactionComponent);
    let newNode = document.createElement('div');
    newNode.id = 'placeholder';
    document.getElementById(id)?.appendChild(newNode);

    const ref = factory.create(this.injector, [], newNode);
    this.app.attachView(ref.hostView);
    
    // save ref
    this.dynamicComponents.push(ref);
    ref.instance.compoRef = ref;
    // Event Listener
    ref.instance.closeMe.subscribe((message: string) => {

    this.removeSpecificDynamicComponent(message)
  });
}
// ....
  removeSpecificDynamicComponent(compo: any) {
    const index = this.dynamicComponents.findIndex(f => f === compo)

    if (index === -1) return;
    this.dynamicComponents[index].destroy();
    this.dynamicComponents.splice(index, 1);
  }
```

#### reaction.component.ts

```
 @Output() closeMe = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Input() compoRef!: ComponentRef<any>;

  close() {
    console.log("CLOSE")
    this.closeMe.emit(this.compoRef);
  }
```

In the end we search for the **dynamic** components `ref` and if we found one we use the destroy function. Per `instance` we can subscribe `@Output` and set `@Input`.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ac65er?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchat-component%2Fchat.component.ts) is the new Stackblitz example.